# How to see remote SSH connections on my server?

Tags: ssh, remote

I'm currently using VSCode's Remote SSH extension to connect to a remote server and edit source code locally.

I was just curious, is there a way to see what connections are established on my remote server? For example, I'm using an SSH client called Xshell to connect to the server. Using Xshell, would there be a command I could run to output what connections are currently established?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ps -Af | grep sshd: | grep @pts
```

will show all the ssh processes for users that are logged in or making an attempt to log in.

How it works:

- `ps -Af` list all the running processes
- `grep sshd:` filters all but those lines with 'sshd:' which is the child process of the ssh daemon.  Each connection gets its own child process.
- `grep @pts` filters all but those lines with '@pts' which is an indicator that a process has been given a terminal shell

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I just tried it and it works great! I had a follow-up question though: I noticed that in the output some usernames have a "+" symbol next to them. Does this have any significant meaning? Also, would I be able to find more information about this piped command by looking through man pages? Thanks agian.

Comment: Yes, look under `man bash` and search for "pipelines".  The `+` symbol I don't know, but put it as a new question and I'm sure someone will have an answer. :-)

Comment: For those like me who were wondering about what `pts` stands for: *pseudo terminal slave*; [difference between pty and tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21280/difference-between-pts-and-tty/21294)